# Como Recriar um Array com valores novos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para pegar um array em Jquery que possui por exemplo 3 valores numéricos e recrio ele com 3 novos valores?

Comment: Apresente melhor o contexto. E, mostre o código que está tentando executar, assim fica mais fácil entender seu problema e responder com clareza.

Comment: A pergunta nao esta clara, qual a logica para 3 valores novos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a função [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map,%20e%20n%C3%A3o%20precisa%20de%20jQuery). Não é necessário usar jQuery pra isso.

Veja um exemplo, existe um *array* com três itens e foi criado um novo *array* com o quadrado destes itens.

```js
const array = [2, 3, 4];

const quadrados = array.map((item) => item * item);

console.log(quadrados);
```